# Xamarin.forms Could not refer a Portable Project.

Tags: forms, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

Using Visual Studio 2017, Xamarin.Forms project is successfully created with Code Sharing Strategy is PCL.

[image]

A class library (portable) ClassLibrary1 is added to the solution:

[image]

It failed when it refer the new library (ClassLibrary1) in the previous library (portable).

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the new class library project (classlibrary1) project file in notepad.   (backup file first) and edit the ProfileId and change it to 259.  Once the class library profile id is the same as the xamarin forms pcl you can add a reference to it

```
<TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile259</TargetFrameworkProfile>
```